# How to track Source/Medium after mail verificaion(Firebase)?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-authentication, tracking

I'm using Firebase Authentication with my React app.
I'm having trouble in Google Analytics to track user Source/Medium.

Flow is like that:

User enters my website > Registers (till now Source/Medium is trackable) >
User verifies email > comes back to website (at this point Source is becoming xxx.firebaseapp.com since the user verified email through firebase services).

So the original Source is lost...

Any ideas?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply 2 changes:

1. In GA property > Referral Exclusion List, add the firebase domain. This is going to tell Google Analytics to ignore that domain as a Referrer and the traffic from firebase.com will appear as Direct / None
2. On the link included on the email add utm parameter so you know the users came from that specific email. E.g. domain.com/emailconfirmation?utm_source=emailVerification&utm_medium=email